# The purpose of function call prologue value $ra in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

The following was the way I was taught to call functions in MIPS in school. I was simply told to "memorize" the "prologue" and the "epilogue", but never explained its concept. Here it is:

First, initialize `$sp`, the stack pointer. Then call `jal f`:

```
li      $sp, 0x7ffffffc
jal     f                # call function f
```

When inside the function, first do the "prologue":

```
sub     $sp, $sp, 8      # set new stack pointer
sw      $ra, 8($sp)      # save return address in stack
sw      $fp, 4($sp)      # save old frame pointer in stack
add     $fp, $sp, 8      # set new frame pointer
```

When returning, do the "epilogue":

```
lw      $ra, 8($sp)      # load return address from stack
lw      $fp, 4($sp)      # restore old frame pointer from stack
add     $sp, $sp, 8      # reset stack pointer
jr      $ra              # return to caller using saved return address
```

**Question:**

The values stored inside `$ra` never changed (unless my functions used it, but I shouldn't be using `$ra` in the first place). The prologue just saved it inside the stack, and restored the **same** value back into `$ra` when returning. `jr` is acting upon the **same thing**, so why is storing `$ra` in the stack necessary in the first place? And why do I need to restore it back if it never changed?

It makes sense to store `$fp` inside the stack because `$fp` was changed. But `$ra` is just the same returning address. Is the processor looking through the stack to match the values inside `$ra` with ones on the stack?

Answer (score 1):

> why is storing $ra in the stack necessary in the first place? And why
>   do I need to restore it back if it never changed?

In your particular case, $ra is never changed. But what would happen if a function calls another function? In that case, $ra would indeed change. In fact your function prologue is missing saving the $sX registers which also (based on MIPS ABI) should be saved by the callee.

> Is the processor looking through the stack to match the values inside
>   $ra with ones on the stack?

No, in MIPS the processor has no understanding of what "stack" is. The stack is a software construct, hardware doesn't care about it.